# What does an exclamation point in the Affdex analysis data mean?

Tags: affdex-sdk

I'm using the Affdex API to analyze facial data. Recently I'm getting back detailed data that periodically has an exclamation point (!) in the data stream, often followed by a very large number (but not always). Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Sample of data is below (just first 30 rows, the first exclamation point occurs on row 12 of the data (13 if you include the header row).

*See my self-answer below, this error was not coming from the API, but rather was occurring when we emailed the results of the analysis*

```
time    anger   contempt    disgust engagement  joy sadness surprise    valence
4.60221025  0.001325006 0.193983853 99.80738068 32.12294006 0.001880687 0.023001779 0.208289847 -87.71645355
4.802306375 0.001677911 0.194810644 99.98110199 55.87456894 0.002214325 0.017005229 0.312710702 -92.3102951
5.0024025   0.003169268 0.195006475 99.99406433 83.60546875 0.003151796 0.008916796 0.743130207 -92.56532288
5.202498584 0.002836938 0.194218457 99.99126434 77.21357727 0.002941116 0.010121359 0.626464069 -90.75523376
5.402594667 0.009874211 0.19438751  99.99804688 98.30487823 0.005840238 0.002880438 3.323126554 -92.83326721
5.60269075  0.025808735 0.197508797 99.99949646 99.85769653 0.010163022 0.001049973 11.93311024 -97.79109192
5.802786875 0.028605226 0.198772311 99.99935913 99.85895538 0.010562016 0.00097405  13.02081203 -97.67404175
6.002882917 0.030434478 0.23800987  99.99925995 99.86201477 0.010959832 0.000897967 14.29151917 -98.50284576
6.202979042 0.028514173 0.482036859 99.99954987 99.89946747 0.011002073 0.000871587 14.72720242 -98.62100983
6.403075125 0.0289828   8.377040863 99.99958038 99.90519714 0.011086978 0.000860611 14.90453911 -98.94358063
6.60317125  0.029681813 6.509725571 99.99938965 99.86938477 0.010796851 0.000906598 14.02865028 -98.7901001
6.803267334 0.008984146 52.43973541 99.99625397 94.56270599 0.00!           
4.67819E+15 0.004179145 2.006785631 -96.28834534                    
7.003363459 0.00394301  92.80983734 99.9903183  71.03998566 0.002959624 0.00922914  0.669553995 -95.29524231
7.203459584 0.001339965 49.45782852 99.99459839 43.49236679 0.001954397 0.020514358 0.240682483 -95.84120941
7.403555625 0.001482374 19.09651947 99.99739838 59.77070236 0.00211753  0.017645501 0.295884103 -97.41999817
7.60365175  0.001694695 19.23854446 99.99807739 69.50489044 0.002312637 0.015203767 0.360884428 -98.44432068
7.803747834 0.01216626  97.45765686 99.99911499 99.27030945 0.006831536 0.002135299 4.839262009 -96.64974213
8.003843959 0.029942503 97.32643127 99.99930573 99.86245728 0.010960344 0.000897158 14.12549782 -99.04064178
8.203940042 0.03000995  95.04572296 99.99934387 99.86806488 0.010994165 0.000893282 14.18607998 -99.07434845
8.404036125 0.033127706 91.09326935 99.99911499 99.83461761 0.010707211 0.000936921 13.47362804 -98.7824707
8.60413225  0.030403215 84.6866684  99.99958038 99.89707184 0.010748477 0.000939324 13.59769726 -98.65213013
8.804228375 0.024669344 63.57430649 99.99960327 99.86995697 0.010104183 0.00104806  11.80122089 -99.12435913
9.004324417 0.027745767 12.36962414 99.99961853 99.90003967 0.010799393 0.000927473 13.64221764 -98.58156586
9.204420584 0.027566336 1.087612987 99.99960327 99.898628234863!                
28  0.0108!                         
5.03141E+12 0.000914909 13.79554081 -98.30038452                    
9.404516625 0.020995114 12.9272728  99.99902344 99.68470764 0.008933282 0.001303476 9.040503502 -97.08209991
9.60461275  0.029310893 93.98880768 99.99944305 99.89394379 0.011078419 0.000875989 14.51346397 -96.45401764
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with how the values are dumped to a file.
Are u using one of the sample apps ?

Comment: Thanks @ahamino, you are basically correct, we're emailing the results out of the App and the data was getting corrupted in that process (see my self-answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in our App which was emailing the results of the analysis. Details were supplied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921111/exclamation-point-in-html-email) on StackOverflow.